# Emitting application event like objects from SQL Server with Service Broker in nodejs

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I want to do something like OracleChangeDatabaseNotitications or PostgreSQL LISTEN/NOTIFY with SQL Server - that is, I want to emit events asynchronously over a connection to the database.

It seems possible to do this from .NET code using ServiceBroker and SQLNotificationServices but I can't find if this is possible to do outside of .NET.

So I tried throwing some JS together.

I used [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steven_bates/2006/01/05/service-broker-example-creation-of-a-simple-queue-and-posting-a-message/) to setup the ServiceBroker environment.

I can send an event like this:

```sql
DECLARE @handle uniqueidentifier
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @handle
FROM SERVICE MyService
TO SERVICE 'MyRecvService'
ON CONTRACT MyContract;
--Sends a message
SEND ON CONVERSATION @handle
MESSAGE TYPE MyMessage('<message>hello world B</message>')
--And ends the conversation
END CONVERSATION @handle WITH CLEANUP
```

And I used the `mssql` package with nodejs to do something like this to try to receive the event:

```js
 let queryResult = await request.query(`declare @rh uniqueidentifier; 
 waitfor( 
   receive top(1) @rh = conversation_handle 
   FROM MyRecvQueue
 ), timeout 20000;
 end conversation @rh;
```

and that DOES return something but only the notification that something happened, not the data.

This is what I get:

```
 query { recordsets: [],      
         recordset: undefined,      
         output: {},                
         rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
```

So it looks like a row has been affected but I'm just throwing the conversation away.

Does anyone know if I can get the data back over the connection without doing a further SQL query?

Comment: Your `receive` only retrieves the `conversation_handle`. You're generally a bit more interested in the `message_body` (`receive top(1) convert(xml, message_body) [message]`). Also, while this is fine for testing purposes, do not create one single conversation per message -- this is massively inefficient. Create conversations once and keep them open for as long as services/applications exist. That eats minimal resources (only space, really) while creating and destroying conversations involves a lot of locking and metadata overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeroen Mostert says... the fix was simple:

```js
let queryResult = await request.query(`declare @rh uniqueidentifier; 
    waitfor(receive top(1) convert(xml, message_body) [message] FROM MyRecvQueue),
            timeout 20000;
    end conversation @rh;`);
```

Does the job.

Thanks!